# UITableViewCell not hiding UIView properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to hide/unhide an `UIView` in the `UITableViewCell`, but many times it unhides it for the wrong `UITableViewCell`. Any suggestions?

---

**cellForRowAtIndexPath function**

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("locationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        var viewWithImage  =  cell?.viewWithTag(22) as UIView!
        var cellHiddenGemView  =  viewWithImage?.viewWithTag(23) as UIView!                        
        var locationObject : PFObject = locationObjects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        var isSecret =  locationObject["isSecret"] as! Bool

        cellHiddenGemView?.hidden = true;

                if isSecret == true
                {
                        cellHiddenGemView?.hidden = false;
                       //this view is unhides for the wrong indexes also
                }        

                return cell;

            }
```

Comment: can you kindly elaborate your question a little more, that on what basis you want to hide/unhide that particular view.

Comment: Why do you have the hardcoded tags? To what do they correspond? If a cell has a view with tag 22, is it an enormous cell with 22 or more subviews? Are you possibly accidentally sharing view objects between multiple cells? Why are you using tags at all, when you can use @IBOutlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its definitely not the best solution to use tags instead of subclassing UITableViewCell and use IBOutlets.

If you would subclass UITableViewCell you could override `prepareForReuse()`
and reset the `hidden` property to *true*

```
func prepareForReuse()
{
   self.HiddenGemView?.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `else` block too. Once this worked for me.

```
 if isSecret == true
 {
    cellHiddenGemView?.hidden = false;
 } 
 else
 {
    cellHiddenGemView?.hidden = true;
 }
```